# '/home/vsts/work/1/a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

my yml is very simple. It builds .net proj1 then copies files and again builds proj2 and copies files. Then it drops zip in the output folder. But after successful build I get the message - '/home/vsts/work/1/a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop. Below is my yml.

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- $(Build.SourceBranchName) 

stages:
- stage: BuildProject
  displayName: buildProj
  jobs:
  - job: Buildproj1
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-2019'
      steps:
        - task: VSBuild@1
          inputs:
            solution: 'Proj1Folder/Proj1/Proj1.csproj'
            msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
            platform: 'Any CPU'
            configuration: 'Release'
            #clean: true

        - task: CopyFiles@2
          inputs:
            sourceFolder: $(System.SourcesDirectory)
            contents: '**\*'
            targetFolder: '$(Build.artifactStagingDirectory)'

  - job: BuildProj2
    dependsOn: BuildProj1
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-2019'
      steps:
        - task: VSBuild@1
          inputs:
            solution: 'Proj2Folder/Proj2/Proj2.csproj''
            msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
            platform: 'Any CPU'
            configuration: 'Release'
            #clean: true

        - task: CopyFiles@2
          inputs:
            sourceFolder: $(System.SourcesDirectory)
            contents: '!*.dll'
            targetFolder: '$(Build.artifactStagingDirectory)'  

  - job: CreateOutput
    dependsOn: BuildProj2
    steps:
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        inputs:
            PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
            ArtifactName: 'drop_$(Build.SourceBranchName)'
            publishLocation: 'Container'

      - task: ArchiveFiles@2
        inputs:
            rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)' 
            includeRootFolder: true 
            archiveType: 'zip' 
            archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip' 
            replaceExistingArchive: true
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using 3 jobs, each job runs on the `new` Microsoft-hosted agent, hence in
your `CreateOutput` job, there is no content in target folder.

I tried your yaml, and have same result:

[image]

Option1:

Put the tasks in one job, use `different` folder under $(Build.artifactStagingDirectory) to store the proj1 and proj2 build result, then work on the $(Build.artifactStagingDirectory) for artifact and archive task.

Add the test yaml here:

```
trigger: none

stages:
- stage: BuildProject
  displayName: buildProj
  jobs:
  - job: Buildproj_1_and_2
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-2019'
    steps:
      - task: Bash@3
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            mkdir "$(Build.artifactStagingDirectory)/job1"
            mkdir "$(Build.artifactStagingDirectory)/job2"
      - task: Bash@3
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            echo 'Job1' >> "$(Build.artifactStagingDirectory)/job1/job1.txt"

      - task: Bash@3
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            echo 'Job2' >> "$(Build.artifactStagingDirectory)/job2/job1.txt"

      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        inputs:
            PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
            ArtifactName: 'drop_$(Build.SourceBranchName)'
            publishLocation: 'Container'

      - task: ArchiveFiles@2
        inputs:
            rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)' 
            includeRootFolder: true 
            archiveType: 'zip' 
            archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip' 
            replaceExistingArchive: true
```

[image]

Option2:

To share files between different jobs, you need to use "PublishPipelineArtifact@1" and "DownloadPipelineArtifact@2"(doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml-task)).

Comment: I tried Option 1 and it didn't work.

Comment: Did you use one job for all tasks? I edited the comment with my yaml and check result, please follow the structure for a check. If the issue persists, please update your yaml in issue description with current one for troubleshooting. thanks.

Comment: - task: CopyFiles@2
          inputs:
            sourceFolder: 'proj1/bin'
            contents: '**\*.*'
            targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/proj1'

I used this to copy the files to respective folders after mkdir followed by build job. It didn't work. Your solution looks good but my context is a bit different I think.

Comment: Before your `CopyFiles` task, use powershell task with inline command `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` to check the file structure of your working directory. Also make sure `proj1` was created under `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`. If you have correct file path defined, the task should work. If any error persists, please let me know the exact error of "it didn't work", thanks.

Comment: Also, in your `CopyFiles` task, remove extra `.` after `**` for `contents`.